# Using Jquery.GetJSON to display numbers from JSON file in HTML/JS, with Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I have seen similar questions but no answer has quite worked for me yet.

I have JSON code at this [address.](http://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest)

I am trying to display the "value_sell" and "value_buy:" objects from "official" and "blue". In Wordpress I have placed the following code in the custom Javascript box:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON( “http://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest?callback=?”,function( data ) {
        jQuery(‘#blue_bid’).text(data.blue.value_buy.toFixed(2));
        jQuery(‘#blue_ask’).text(data.blue.value_sell.toFixed(2));
        jQuery(‘#official_bid’).text(data.oficial.value_buy.toFixed(2));
        jQuery(‘#official_ask’).text(data.oficial.value_sell.toFixed(2));
    });
});'
```

The following is the HTML table using variables to display values, but it does not display anything:

```
<aside class="widget wbluedollar">
<table width=200 cellpadding=3 bordercolor=white border=none>

<tr width=200>
<td style="background: linear-gradient(blue, #0000bb);color:white;" width="100">
<div style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:.8em;">Dollar Blue</div>
</td>
<td style="background: linear-gradient(#00bb00, green);color:white;" width="100">
<div style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:.8em;">Dollar Official</div>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="color:#0000bb; font-size:.8em;">BUY: <span id="blue_bid">
<br>SELL: <span id="blue_ask">
</div></td>
<td>
<div style="color:#00bb00; font-size:.8em;">BUY: <span id="official_bid>
<br>SELL: <span id="official_ask"></div></td>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="color:grey; font-size:.7em;">Powered by 
<a href=http://bluelytics.com.ar/>Bluelytics</a>
</div></td>
</table>
```

Any suggestions on where the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: see console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper quotes,properly close the dom elements

```
<tr width=200>
<td style="background: linear-gradient(blue, #0000bb);color:white;" width="100">
<div style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:.8em;">Dollar Blue</div>
</td>
<td style="background: linear-gradient(#00bb00, green);color:white;" 

    width="100">
    <div style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:.8em;">Dollar Official</div>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div style="color:#0000bb; font-size:.8em;">BUY: <span id="blue_bid"></span>
            <br>SELL: <span id="blue_ask"></span>
    </div></td>
    <td>
        <div style="color:#00bb00; font-size:.8em;">BUY: <span id="official_bid"></span>
    <br>SELL: <span id="official_ask"></div></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div style="color:grey; font-size:.7em;">Powered by 
    <a href=http://bluelytics.com.ar/>Bluelytics</a>
    </div></td>
    </table>
```

js:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON( "http://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest?callback=?",function( data ) {
        jQuery("#blue_bid").text(data.blue.value_buy.toFixed(2));
        jQuery("#blue_ask").text(data.blue.value_sell.toFixed(2));
        jQuery("#official_bid").text(data.oficial.value_buy.toFixed(2));
        jQuery("#official_ask").text(data.oficial.value_sell.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vr9e619k/

Comment: This worked--just the quotes seemed to be the issue then?

Comment: close the span tags and other tags that aren't close